# Using javascript parameter inside jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a function that returns the count of th tags in a table:

```
function addTotals(targetTable) {
var colCount = $("#" + targetTable.id th).size();

return colCount
}
```

And I'm getting an error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using wrong selector. It should be:

```
var colCount = $("#" + targetTableId+" th").length;
return colCount;
```

or

```
var colCount = $("#" + targetTableId).find("th").length;
return colCount;
```

Comment: Actually the variable colCount is redundant. Just do the return itself.

Comment: I changed the syntax of my function, but I'm guessing your answer still applies. Thanks! :)

Comment: @A.Wolff: Thanks..you are right. using property length is good practice..

Comment: @Zephram: it will always work if you are passing valid `targetTableId` :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this might help

function addTotals(targetTableId)

{

var colCount = $('table name').find('th name').length() ;

return colCount;

}